# Msiexec a MSI package with passive got different results in administrator command prompt and normal command prompt

Tags: wix, windows-installer, sccm

I tried to make up wxs to build a MSI package. The target is to passive install in Standard User account. This MSI copies files, writes HKCU registry, creates folder under %LOCALAPPDATA% and creates a shortcut on desktop, as follows.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
 <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Hello RMA">
       <Component Id="files" Guid="{0f8e0c9f-5248-4a88-90a3-8f08564bf7b9}">...</Component>
   
       <Component Id="Mode" Guid="{0ee73a0b-a204-4e0f-a604-8057f69ad837}" Win64="yes">
            <RegistryValue Id="Mode" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Hello RMA" Name="Mode" Value="Tablet" Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
       </Component>
       <Directory Id="Application_Dir" Name="Application">
           <Component Id="chrome_100_percent.pak" Guid="{eec8284f-d402-490a-a017-91f42779c848}">
                <File ... />
                ...
           </Component>                         
           <Component Id="HelloRMA.exe" Guid="{b973cdcc-d9e5-4cd2-903a-7e8886504833}" Win64="yes">
                <File Id="HelloRMA.exe" Name="Hello RMA.exe" Vital="no" DiskId="1" Source="payload\Application\Hello RMA.exe" />
                <Shortcut Id="HelloRMA.exe_1" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="Hello RMA" Target="[#HelloRMA.exe]" Description="Hello RMA.exe" Hotkey="0" IconIndex="0" Show="normal" WorkingDirectory="Application_Dir" />
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Hello RMA" Name="UI installed" Value="1" Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
           </Component>                
       </Directory>
    </Directory>
 </Directory>
 <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="DesktopFolder" />
 
 <!-- Create folders in AppData -->
 <Directory Id="LocalAppDataFolder" Name="LocalAppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="HelloRMA_Dir" Name="Hello RMA">
        <Directory Id="NewFolder_Dir" Name="log">
            <Component Id="NewFolder" Guid="{7afcd67e-079b-4619-8430-f4ee7ef41275}">
                <CreateFolder Directory="NewFolder_Dir" />
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Hello RMA" Name="Log folder installed" Value="1" Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
                <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveLogDir" Directory="NewFolder_Dir" On="uninstall" />
                <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveRMADir" Directory="HelloRMA_Dir" On="uninstall" />                          
            </Component>
        </Directory>                
    </Directory>
 </Directory>
```

It works well when running it with the following command under normal command prompt with prompt for credentials.

```
msiexec /i rma.msi /passive
```

If running the same command under administrator command prompt, registry, folders in %LOCALAPPDATA% and shortcut would not be installed. Only files were copied to INSTALLDIR.
Why are they different? Anything wrong in my WXS?

Another question is I wonder if MSI is deployed to user PC by SCCM. What environment will it be executed? Administrator command prompt or normal command prompt?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A verbose log file would tell you for sure. However, I bet the missing files and registry keys are still being installed but installed into a different user profile where you are not looking.

All the resources you list as "missing" are installed to the user profile (`LocalAppDataFolder` and `HKCU`), so they will be installed to the user profile that launched the install.

So my guess is that your elevated command prompt is running as a different user than your normal command prompt.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Due to prompt for credentials, new folders and registry were created to  local administrator account.